# Generate predictions using JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-networks, rjags

I have a parametrised linear Gaussian Bayesian network and I am trying to make predictions on the model using `rjags`. I can do this for one observation but do not know how to pass multiple observations. Here is an example

```
library(rjags)
library(coda)
```

Initial model

```
mod <- textConnection("model {
  mpg.hat <- (34.96055404 - 3.35082533* wt - 0.01772474* disp)
  wt      ~ dnorm(3.21725, 1/0.9784574^2)
  disp    ~ dnorm(230.7219, 1/123.9387^2)
  mpg     ~ dnorm(mpg.hat, 1/2.916555^2)
}")

# Evaluate and get prediction when wt=1 and disp is hidden
m <- jags.model(mod, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 1000, data=list(wt=1, disp=NA))
update(m, 10000)
cs <- coda.samples(m,  c("mpg", "wt", "disp"),  1e5)
summary(cs)
```

This works as expected, however, I have multiple rows of data that I want to generate predictions for. If I try to extend the `data=list(` argument to include more rows it throws an error. So after rerunning the model text, and the following command I get the error

```
m <- jags.model(mod, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 1000, data=list(wt=1:2, disp=1:2))
```

> Error in jags.model(mod, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 1000, data = list(wt = 1:2,  : 
>     Error in node dnorm(230.722,(a1/(a123.939^2))) 
>   Length mismatch in Node::setValue

How do I extend this to more observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the rows:

```
mod <- textConnection("model {
  for (n in 1:N) {
    mpg.hat[n] <- (34.96055404 - 3.35082533* wt[n] - 0.01772474* disp[n])
    mpg[n]     ~ dnorm(mpg.hat[n], 1/2.916555^2)
    wt[n]      ~ dnorm(3.21725, 1/0.9784574^2)
    disp[n]    ~ dnorm(230.7219, 1/123.9387^2)
  }
}")
```

Note you will need to add `N` to your data list as well:

```
data = list(N = 1, wt = 1, disp = NA)
data = list(N = 2, wt = 1:2, disp = 1:2)
```